# block datepickerdate according to array data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I am using `UIDatePickerView` to show next 7 days. For this I am using this code

```
NSDate *sevenDays = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*7];
//Then you can use in DatePicker as of your below Code.

ActionSheetDatePicker *datePicker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] 
    initWithTitle:@"Select Date" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate 
    selectedDate:[NSDate date] minimumDate:[NSDate date] 
    maximumDate:sevenDays target:self 
    action:@selector(timeWasSelected:element:) origin:sender];
```

. Now I want to block the date which is coming in NSArray

```
BlockDate =     (
                {
            endtime = 13;
            hdaydate = "2016-09-16";
            starttime = 7;
        },
                {
            endtime = 22;
            hdaydate = "2016-09-15";
            starttime = 16;
        }
    );.
```

How to block the `UIDatePickerView` date as per `NSArray` data?

Comment: You mean that you want to transform these two `NSDictionary` into two `NSDate`? What have you tried? Did you succeed in parsing that Array ? Did you look at `NSDateFormatter` and `NSDateComponents`?

Comment: @Larme yes sir the date of hdaydate should be disable in pickerview not able to select anyone or hide that date in pickerview

Answer (score 1):

You can't customize the appearance of a UIDatePicker, but you can register for the `valueChanged` event and then programmatically skip the selected date.
Problem here is, that the user won't be able to recognize, which date is selectable, which is not a good experience.

I would suggest, to use a [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerview) and build the list of available dates by leaving out the 'blocked' dates.